# How to ask about another person's job

Tags: idiomaticity

What are the questions that one can ask to find out another person's job? Are the following correct/appropriate?

> (a) Was machen Sie beruflich?
>
> (b) Was sind Sie von Beruf?
>
> (c) Was machen Sie?
>
> (d) Was arbeiten Sie?
>
> (e) **Wie** arbeiten Sie?
>
> (f) Was ist Ihre Arbeit?
>
> (g) **Wie** ist Ihre Arbeit?

Comment: (e) and (g) have other meanings. (e) as it stands right now is pretty uncommon. It could be used in a sentence like "Wie arbeiten Sie unter Zeitdruck?", suggesting the question if someone is able to work without worry or haste, but though quickly and efficient when time is running out. - (g) asks if a job or task is interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) would be the best question, (b,c,d,f) are also correct.
(e) is not correct and (g) means: "How do you like your job?"

Answer (score 2):

I´m not a native German speaker, but I used to study in a Goethe-Institut. I learned there (and used to heard) form **B**:

> *Was sind Sie von Beruf*?

**A**, **D** and **F** also sound OK. But **C** sounds to me a little too broad to be interpreted as a question specifically about someone's job.

Comment: If context is given, C is absolutely fine. Without context, you're right.